# Featured Image Thumbnail size on Twenty Ten Archive Page

Tags: images

I have figured out how to get a thumbnail to appear on a twenty ten archive page but I cannot figure out how to resize it to say a size of "150px" by "150px".

For example, on the following page the featured image is showing the full width of the post excerpt, I just want it 150px wide on the left hand side of the post excerpt and the large full size image to appear on the actual post page once you click and read the full post.

See: http://www.westlimerickphysio.com/category/physiotherapynews/

I hope I am making myself clear.

Regards, Noel.

Answer (score 1):

At first, make sure your thumbnails are set to size 150x150 in "Settings/Media".
If they are not, you may have to regenerate your thumbnails after setting the new size. [This Plugin helps you here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/)

In your template, be sure to call the 'thumbnail' size of the image:

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail' );
```

you should be fine after that. If not, please write the line of code where you output the image.

Comment: Thtanks for reply fischi. thumbnails are set to size 150x150 in "Settings/Media". I'm using twentyten child theme, what file should I enter above code in?

Comment: are you using the standard twentyten theme? it looks as if you have put your image into the content, so it shows up in the excerpt. you can insert the post thumbnail directly in the template, loop.php, lines 111 and 139, where you can find "<?php the_excerpt(); ?>, add one line before the excerpt with the aboce mentioned code.